# Select people based on turning 18 in the last 12 to 15 months

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a database of names date if births and address. I would like to be able to create a query that shows anyone that has turned 18 in the last 12 to fifteen months.
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve  this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding some examples of what your source table looks like

Comment: What do you mean 12-15 months ago? anyone who turned 18 in the last 12 months also turned 18 in the 15 months - so are you wanting "turned 18 in the last 15 months" or turned 18 more than 12 months ago but less than 15 months ago"?

Comment: Thanks @G B, I was not clear. I need to know who has had there 18th Birthday more than 12 months ago but less than 15 months ago. @Smog  The  Tables structure is simple. 'name', 'address', 'date of birth'.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact syntax in access, but basically do that (pseudocode):

```
Select ... Where dateadd(birthday, year, 18) between dateadd(today, month, -15) and dateadd(today, month, -12)
```